# How to combine the enumerated document to the original document using python?

Tags: python, text

First, I want to enumerate a document which contains more than two sentences as shown below:

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice"""
doc1 = doc.split('.')
list = []
for i in enumerate(doc1):
     list.append(i)
```

For each sentence, I am finding a sentiment score, then I want to combine the enumerated document to the original format by taking average of the score.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated?

```
doc2 = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice"""
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want from: "Second, I want to combine the enumerated document to the original format." ?

Comment: The output should be like the original document 'doc1'

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you on this - if you have access to the original document and its contents, why are you trying to rebuild it?

Comment: I am finding score for each sentence and then I want to combine it to the original document by taking average.

Comment: average of what exactly?

Comment: sentiment score for each sentence.

Comment: In that case, to rebuild the document is trivial - since your document is not complex, all you have to do is the inverse operation of `split` which is `join`: i.e. `""".""".join(doc1)`.

Comment: Joining from that is easy: `'.'.join(j for _, j in list_)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've really understood your question.

Note that your code is equivalent to:

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice"""
doc1 = doc.split('.')
result = list(enumerate(doc1))
```

(I've used `result` because `list` would hide the name `list` I use to construct the list)

If you put

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice"""
```

as input you'll get in `result` the value

```
result = [(0,"I like movie"),(1," But I don't like the cast"),(2," The story is very nice")]
```

> Note the spaces at the begining of the strings. It may or may not be what you're looking for.

## Basic result

If you're question is "How to recreate the initial string given the result ?", here is a sample code to do that:

```
recreated_doc = ".".join(value for index, value in result)
```

## Advanced answer

Note that if you provide

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice."""
```

with a ending comma, you'll get:

```
result = [(0,"I like movie"),(1," But I don't like the cast"),(2," The story is very nice"),(3,"")]
```

But what if I want to get the next line instead ?

```
result = [(0,"I like movie"),(1,"But I don't like the cast"),(2,"The story is very nice")]
```

(Notice that there is no spaces at the start of the strings, nor empty strings.)

Here will be the code:

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice."""
doc1 = doc.split('.')
doc2 = (part.strip(' ') for part in doc1)
doc3 = (part for part in doc2 if len(part) > 0)
result = list(enumerate(doc3))
# result = [(0, 'I like movie'), (1, "But I don't like the cast"), (2, 'The story is very nice')]
```

And to recrete the original string:

```
recreated_doc = " ".join(value+"." for index, value in result)
# recreated_doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice."""
```

> Warning, the advanced solution doesn't recreate always the same original doc, so it may be a no go.

Example:

```
doc = """This a document with a lot of spaces.   .   Too much spaces here.       And also here     .   ."""
# [...]
# recreated_doc = """This a document with a lot of spaces. Too much spaces here. And also here."""
```

Comment: Thank you @gissehel. This is what I am expecting "recreated_doc = ".".join(value for index, value in result)"